# multivariate linear regression inputs fitting

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am working on machine learning project I am doing a multivariate linear regression model in python and here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_csv("train.csv", delimiter=",", header=0)
x = data['Col1'][:, np.newaxis]
y = data['Expected']
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x, y)
```

my train.csv file contains 3 columns Col1,Col2,Expected so x will contain the input "Col1" and "Col2" records while y will be the putput "Expected" records . I manged to put only one input in x which is Col1 but I cannot put Col2 in x.

How to save the values of the two columns Col1 and Col2 in x to be fitted in the linear regression later?

---

```
>>>> print(data.head())
          Col1     Col2  Expected
      0   7.645   5.2119      46.0
      1   7.079   3.4145      28.7
      2  91.900  24.0000      50.0
      3   5.875   1.1296      50.0
      4   6.153   3.2797      29.6
```

Comment: Please post the result of  `data.head()`

Comment: `Col1     Col2  Expected`
`0   7.645   5.2119      46.0`
`1   7.079   3.4145      28.7`
`2  91.900  24.0000      50.0`
`3   5.875   1.1296      50.0`
`4   6.153   3.2797      29.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
x = data[['Col1', 'Col2']]
```